# iCloud Drive storage is full

Tags: icloud, storage, macos

I've just upgraded my OS to Sierra and have turned on the "optimize storage" option for iCloud Drive. But strangely I now get a "your iCloud storage is full" message.

[image: info size]
[image: total size]
When I checked my local drive, it seems the total size of all folders inside wasn't the same as the iCloud Drive information. When I dive into iCloud preferences the Document size is insanely huge. How do I find out which ones are the large files?

---

**[UPDATE]**

I don't have any large files in my Documents folder. But it's strange:
[image]

Comment: How big is the actual Documents folder on your hard drive? (username > Documents)

Comment: it's only 786 megabytes @tubedogg

Comment: Do you have anything else in iCloud storage, such as iCloud Photo Library or a device backup?

Comment: No I don't think so. I've updated my screenshots. @tubedogg

Comment: Something's clearly taking 4.7 GB. Login on icloud.com, click Settings on the main screen and there will be a bar categorizing what is taking up room in your storage.

Comment: I've been having the same issue. Can't find what is taking up all that space... Did you solve your issue, @pacific01 ?